# Using SparkleShare with Git

Tags: macos, git, sparkleshare

I am using SparkleShare, but someone I am working with would be more comfortable using git. Can he use my SparkleShare repository by just using git?

Here's what I know.

If I go to my local SparkleShare directory and run

```
git remote show origin
```

I can find the URL and then go to another new directory and clone the repository.

Working in the cloned directory, I can add files and push them to the repository.

Back in my original local directory, nothing shows up from SparkleShare. However, I can show that it has changed by

```
git ls-remote
```

and

```
git pull
```

pulls the new file into the original local directory.

SparkleShare still seems to know nothing about it. However, if I now edit it and save it, SparkleShare updates everything as it normally does.

So my question is, what set of git commands can I use to make SparkleShare recognize the changes that have been made to the repository, without making a new commit by editing a file?

(I am doing this using the Terminal on OS X  10.9.1)